# Accessing directive's isolate scope from "this" with the controllerAs syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am unable to access a directive's isolated scope's variables from this with the `controllerAs` syntax / style.

I could access the variables with `$scope`, but that does not seem to be consistent. Is there way to access the isolated scope's variables with `this`?

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/srph/13d528e566e0c3b0729c) of my controller and directive.

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: In your directive settings try set [`bindToController:true`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-bindtocontroller-) at `return {
      scope: scope,
      restrict: 'EA',
      transclude: true,
      template: getTemplate,
      controller: 'PaginationCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'pagination',bindToController:true
    };`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are using isolated scope directive with controller as syntax and using *angular 1.3*, you can easily bind the scope bindings to the controller now by turning on **[`bindToController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-bindtocontroller-)**  setting on the directive so that scope bindings are attached to the controller instance automatically. In your case do:-

```
return {
  scope: scope,
  restrict: 'EA',
  transclude: true,
  template: getTemplate,
  controller: 'PaginationCtrl',
  controllerAs: 'pagination',
  bindToController:true //<-- Here
};
```